# ContentProtocol.Protocol is not convertible to Protocol

Tags: ios7, swift, xcode6

How to check if some object conforms to a protocol ?

I tried this way but I get an error:

```
    if lCell.conformsToProtocol(ContentProtocol) {

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out these code examples by apple, they describe exactly what you are trying to accomplish:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-XID_408

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure `ContentProtocol` is an `@objc` protocol.
- Make sure you are using the latest Xcode beta (at least Xcode 6 beta 3)
- By the way, you should use `is` to test conformance to a protocol that is fixed at compile time (or use `as` or `as?` and perform optional binding):

.

```
if lCell is ContentProtocol
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if let cell = lCell as? ContentProtocol {
   cell.doSomething();
}
```

See **Checking for Protocol Conformance** in [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-XID_408).